# Uncaught ReferenceError PouchDB

Tags: javascript, sql, pouchdb, cloudant

I am currently using PouchDB as my DB and I am using Cloudant for the remote service. I am currently trying to create document, however, when I invoke the function, I have errors.

May I know where did I do wrong? Could it be the URL wrong or my syntax is wrong?

> Uncaught Reference Error: PouchDB is not a constructor

This is my javascript code

```
   function pouchdb() {
        var db = new PouchDB("todos");

        var remoteDB = new PouchDB("http://example.cloudant.com/example");
        window.PouchDB = db;
        var doc = {
        "_id": "Can123",
        "name": "You123",
        "occupation": "See1",
        "age": 3,
        "hobbies": [
          "Watch 9pm show",
          "chasing laser pointers",
          "lookin' hella cute"
        ]
    };

    db.put(doc);        
PouchDB.sync(db, remoteDB);

}
```

HTML code

```
<button onclick="pouchdb()">pouchdb</button>
```

> Update

I changed my insert code for this set of code

```
function pouchdb() {
    var db = new PouchDB("todos");

    var remoteDB = new PouchDB("http://example.cloudant.com/example");
    var todo = {
        _id: "mittens1233",
        title: "hello",
        occupation: "kitten123"
    };
    db.put(todo, function callback(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Successfully posted a todo!');
        }
    });
}
```

The result i got back is `Successfully posted a todo!`, however, my cloudant dashboard still shows 0 doc. May I know why?

Comment: `PouchDB` isn't a constructor. Undeclare `new` in `new PouchDB(...)`.

Comment: @TheProHands so it'd be  `var db = PouchDB("todos"); `
`var remoteDB = PouchDB("http://example.cloudant.com/example");` ?

Comment: Well, if that's the error, that's right, but the library says it's a constructor after I seen its page.

Comment: @TheProHands I've seen other pages example, they did `new PouchDB(...)` as well.. so I highly doubt that's the error?

Comment: Did you click the buttons 2 or more times?

Comment: Is PouchDB loaded properly? (BTW you should avoid doing `window.PouchDB = db;` because `window.PouchDB` is already being used for the PouchDB function, and overwriting globals can result in weird bugs.)

Comment: @TheProHands I did clicked once only, tried but cloudant database did not have any document created still.

Comment: @gcampbell is there any command i can call to check if PouchDB is loaded properly? Will remove the `window.PouchDB =db` and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that line

```
window.PouchDB = db;
```

I think that's the problem. Once you click the button, the global `PouchDB` turns the variable `db`, what makes it not be a constructor anymore.

If the error still continues, @gcampbell comment should be right?

Comment: now there's no error, however, i tried executing the insert function but my cloudant still doesn't show any doc being created. is there a problem with my host link or something?

Comment: @Alvin Try to check this page: https://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html#write_todos_to_database. You could add a callback for the `put` method in 2nd parameter, then say the result for us.

Comment: hi, i have updated and showed the result given. but problem persist, may i know why?

Comment: @Alvin Can you open a new question giving all information of what are you doing? I'm not sure how does this library work, but I'll try to learn it.

Comment: Alright, i will get a new question open for this cloudant issue. Thanks!

Comment: New question created [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725473/pouchdb-on-cloudant)