# PouchDB on Cloudant

Tags: javascript, sql, pouchdb, cloudant

I am currently using PouchDB and I am making use of Cloudant to make my db in PouchDB to be on cloud.

I did callback method and it gave a success callback, however, I check my database on Cloudant, there's 0 doc created but there's 8 update seq.

May I know why? This is my set of code I used.

```
function pouchdb() {

    var db = new PouchDB("todos");
    var remoteDB = new PouchDB("http://example.cloudant.com/example");

    var todo = {
        _id: "mittens1233",
        title: "hello",
        occupation: "kitten123"
    };

    db.put(todo, function callback(err, result) {
        if (!err)
            console.log('Successfully posted a todo!');
    });

    db.put(doc);
    PouchDB.sync(db, remoteDB);

}
```

The result i got back is

`Successfully posted a todo!`

Comment: Maybe `http://example.cloudant.com/example` isn't the right db link. I think you must link the database created in your account.

Comment: @TheProHands in my actual code, i set it as `http://USERNAME.cloudant.com/DATABASE` whereby 'USERNAME' is my username and 'DATABASE' is the name of my database.

Comment: @TheProHands i solved the issue already, i posted my own solution. thank you so much for your help so far! appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

My error was because the host link I was using was incorrect. It should be in a format of http://username:password@mycluster.cloudant.com . I generated an API key and used the key as username and password as password. Then it worked. I was able to create and query document.